# Is there anything with my flow of thoughts/code?

Tags: c

The point of this code is to use a recursive function to reverse the array.

For example: `arr = 1, 2, 3`
Output should be `3, 2, 1`

This is the code I came up with.
I was wondering if there is anything wrong with my thought process.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void rReverseAr(int ar[], int size);

int main()
{
    int array[80];
    int size, i;
    printf("Enter size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d numbers: \n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    printf("rReverseAr(): ");
    rReverseAr(array, size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void rReverseAr(int ar[], int size)
{
    int temp[size], i = 0;
    if (size == 1)
        temp[i] = ar[size-1];
    else {
        temp[i] = ar[size-1];
        i++;
        rReverseAr(ar, size-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
       ar[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: What does your testing suggest?  Does the program seem to work as intended?

Comment: @JohnBollinger if i run the code. lets say input 1 2 3. the output will be 3 41431442 421312431.

Comment: You should be able to reverse the array in situ without needing the temporary array `temp` in the function — even when using recursion.

Comment: every time when there is a recursive call there is an initialization of temp array and "i=0" so every time when the function is called array is empty and temp[0] is updated

Comment: I think your recursive regime should be: if size <= 1 return; swap first and last; recurse on array + 1, size - 2.  That certainly works.  You can use a simple variable instead of an array when swapping.

Comment: Consider an array of 1 element, how would you reverse it? How would you revers an arrray of two elements? After swapping the first and last element in a longer array, where are the elements you still need to swap? More precisely, do you think the first element needs swapping again? The output you show seems unplausible to me. Please show a complete session, with prompts your input to each prompt and the output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you. your comments really helped. managed to do it more elegantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for things which are wrong with your thoughts and code.
You are not asking for a code solution, which I respect very much.
So here is your functionally unchanged code, with things commented which you should think about.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rReverseAr(int ar[], int size);

int main()
{
    int array[80]; /* with this array you should make sure
                      that users size is <=80 */
    int size, i;   /* always initialise your variables */
    printf("Enter size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size); /* always check the return value of scanf(),
                           the return value, not the scanned value */

    printf("Enter %d numbers: \n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]); /* return value ... */

    printf("rReverseAr(): ");
    rReverseAr(array, size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void rReverseAr(int ar[], int size)
{
    int temp[size], i = 0;
    /* quoting Johnathan Lefflers comment:
       You should be able to reverse the array in situ
       without needing the temporary array temp in the function
       - even when using recursion. */ 

    if (size == 1)
        temp[i] = ar[size-1]; /* reconsider the necessity to reverse an array of size 1 */
    else {
        temp[i] = ar[size-1]; /* you overwrite index 0, 
                                 don't you think you still need it?
                                 Think back to when you learned how to swap
                                 the values of two variables...
                                 Even swapping by copying into a temp array,
                                 you still need to do something about the
                                 other value.
                                 Even if you do not actually attempts to swap
                                 two values and only intend to go recursively
                                 through the array and only move one end, you need
                                 to move the end which you actually modified. */
        i++; /* you increase something which then is never used again... */
        rReverseAr(ar, size-1); /* After swapping (assuming successfully) the 
                                   first and last element, do you really want
                                   to swap the array which begins with the same,
                                   already swapped, first element ? 
                                   Remember that increasing i does not have an
                                   effect on this... */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)    /* only necessary because of the temp array decision... */ 
       ar[i] = temp[i];
}
```

(*I am also quite close to Johnathan Lefflers second comment, which I agree with.

I do not consider it quoted though...*)

Comment: Concerning the use of `scanf()` I recommend http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Blindly initializing variables is a potential waste of code space and run time and mainly shows that the author doesn't know what he's doing. Better define variables as late as possible so there are no doubts about the state of them. Raise the compiler warning level to the max. And finally, double writes without a read in between is a code smell.

Comment: @thebusybee That is applicable for code which then reliably write values to the variables. Which this code does not in all cases. Defining variables, initialising and first writing them are different things. Only initialising when if needed is an optimisation, for which the ban on premature optimisation applies. It also is an optimisation for more experienced programmers which can afford to take additional risks. Yes, I agree that it is an optimisation.

Comment: To clarify, being experienced and being allowed to take additional (maintenance) risks are of course to separate things. I meant ".. which are also allowed to take additional risks...".